# How to make multilevel index for firebase realtime database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, indexing

I want to setup multi-level index in my firebase realtime database. My database structure looks like this, in which the root key name is `jobOpenings` which contains child of job opening id (for instance `particularJobId`) which is going to contain sub child of jobApplications which contains the user information such as **age**, **firstName**, etc.

Here is a snapshot of my data
[image]

I have made my index rules like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",  
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "jobOpenings": {
        "particularJobId" : {
          ".indexOn" : ".value"
        }
    },
  }
}
```

But I couldn't able to find the users by their `firstName`. My query looks like this

```
const activeUserRef = ref(database, 'jobOpenings/particularJobId');
        const searchQuery = query(
            activeUserRef,
            orderByValue('firstName'),
            equalTo(searchInput)
        );
        const snapshot = await get(searchQuery);
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                console.log(child.val());
            });
        } else {
            console.log('No data found');
        }
```

Is it my query wrong or my indexing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes should do the trick:

**Rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",  
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "jobOpenings": {
        "particularJobId" : {
          ".indexOn" : ["age", "firstName", ...]
        }
    },
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
const activeUserRef = ref(db, 'jobOpenings/particularJobId');
const searchQuery = query(
  activeUserRef,
  orderByChild('firstName'),
  equalTo(searchInput)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`orderByValue()` doesn't take a parameter, you can use `orderByChild()` to order your result:

```
   const searchQuery = query(
       activeUserRef,
       orderByChild('firstName'),
       equalTo(searchInput)
     );
```

And the `equalTo()` should contain same value as the one you have in the database.

Check here for API reference:

[orderByValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#orderbyvalue)

[orderByChild()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#orderbychild)